# Starting a widget app as a thread within Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5

*Python3*

Trying to run some code that does the following:

1. Creates two threads using the Threading module.
2. Starts a QApplication from the PyQt5.QtWidgets module.

I've tried starting the application first and using the app to start a thread -- Unfortunately, I am not too familiar with the *QtWidgets*.

**This is the CODE:**

```
import time
import sys
import threading
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

def main():
    pass

# THREADING Function 1
def print_interval( threadName, delay):
   count = 0
   while count < 5:
      time.sleep(delay)
      count += 1
      print( "%s: %s" % ( threadName, tm.ctime(time.time()) ))

#THREADING Function 2
def startAPP():
    app = QApplication([])
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    window = QWidget()
    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(QPushButton('Top'))
    layout.addWidget(QPushButton('Bottom'))
    layout.addWidget(QFontDialog('Left'))
    window.setLayout(layout)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for x in range(0, 4):
        sys.stdout.write('\r'+"Loading" + "." * x)
        time.sleep(1)

    main()
    # Create two threads as follows
    try:
        thread1 = threading.Thread()
        thread1.target = print_interval('name',4)
        thread1.start()

        thread2 = threading.Thread()
        thread2.target = startAPP()
        thread2.start()
    except:
       print("Error: unable to start thread")
    while 1:
       pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least the following errors:

- To the target you must not pass the evaluated function but it is a callable one, in your case the targets are evaluated functions.
- For design reasons Qt prohibits running the GUI on a secondary thread so the second thread is unnecessary and you must change it instead of while True.
- QFontDialog expects as a argument a QFont or QWidget or both but not a string.

```py
import time
import sys
import threading
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


def main():
    pass


# THREADING Function 1
def print_interval(threadName, delay):
    count = 0
    while count < 5:
        time.sleep(delay)
        count += 1
        print("%s: %s" % (threadName, time.ctime(time.time())))


# THREADING Function 2
def startAPP():
    app = QApplication([])
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    window = QWidget()
    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(QPushButton("Top"))
    layout.addWidget(QPushButton("Bottom"))
    layout.addWidget(QFontDialog())
    window.setLayout(layout)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for x in range(0, 4):
        sys.stdout.write("\r" + "Loading" + "." * x)
        time.sleep(1)

    main()
    # Create two threads as follows
    try:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=print_interval, args=("name", 1))
        thread.start()
    except:
        print("Error: unable to start thread")
    startAPP()
```

Comment: Fantastic, much appreciated!